# How to count characters of SET command batch and "encrypt" it

Tags: batch-file, encryption

I'm in need, again.
This time I need in a way count characters from the command SET, is there any way?
So here is my code, I need to "encrypt" the password to *'s and echo it.
Here's my code:

```
:REGISTER
CLS
SET /P USERNAME=Username: 
SET /P PASSWORD=Password: 
CLS
ECHO Username: %USERNAME%
ECHO Password: ******** <<<<< Here's where i wan't to "encrypt" the password to *'s
SET /P CONFIRM_PASSWORD=Confirm password: 
:MOREcodes
```

EDIT: Thanks for the awnser [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd)!
So i did like this:

```
    @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /P PASSWORD=Password: 
CLS
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('CMD /V:ON /Q /U /C"ECHO(^!PASSWORD^!"^|MORE'
) DO (
SET "HIDDEN_PASSWORD=!HIDDEN_PASSWORD!*"
)
ECHO Password: %HIDDEN_PASSWORD%
PAUSE
SETLOCAL DISABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    :: save value into password variable

    set "password=0123456789 <&!**$."

    :: echo value to console (to test length)

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo(!password!
    endlocal

    :: echo *s for each character in password

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        'cmd /v:on /q /u /c"echo(!password!"^|more'
    ) do (set/p"=*"<nul)
```

**edited** to adapt to comments. Store the *s in a variable

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "password=0123456789 <&^!**$."

    set "maskedPassword="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        'cmd /v:on /q /u /c"echo(^!password^!"^|more'
    ) do (
        set "maskedPassword=!maskedPassword!*"
    )

    echo(!password!
    echo(%maskedPassword%
```

Comment: Perfect, but how do I save the *'s to a variable?